# Нужно ли здесь тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?
Однако в веке двадцать первом – в цифровую эпоху –  чем больше мы погружаемся в компьютерные технологии, медиапространство и виртуальную реальность, тем больше наш мир начинает походить на иллюзию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Можно оставить предложенный вариант**:

Однако в веке двадцать первом – **в цифровую эпоху** – чем больше мы погружаемся в компьютерные технологии, медиапространство и виртуальную реальность, тем больше наш мир начинает походить на иллюзию.

1) На  выбор тире при обособлении приложений влияют такие  факторы  как **добавочный характер значения** и распространенность, например: Лёгкие судороги –  **признак сильного волнения** –  пробежали по его щекам.   Рыбак –  **типичный севастопольский старик с худым от ветра лицом** –  сидел на земле и латал рваную сеть.

2) Обычно СПП с союзом ЧЕМ...ТЕМ располагаются в начале предложения или используются в сложных предложениях, **реже перед союзом находится обстоятельство**, причем запятая между союзом и обстоятельством не ставится: Сейчас чем больше производишь, тем хуже. В молодости чем больше родных, тем лучше, удобнее.

Из этого следует, что **дополнительных запятых при обособлении приложения с помощью тире  не требуется**.

Comment: В Ваших примерах приложения, а в приведённом автором - поясняющее обстоятельство. Или Вы его разберёте как определение? Когда? в веке двадцать первом,(а каком именно? что он из себя представляет? - " в цифровую эпоху", поясняет обстоятельство и само является обстоятельством.

Comment: 1)  Обособление с помощью тире используется для различных членов предложения, например: И необычайный – смутный и зловещий – гул доносился от этой страшной человеческой массы. 2)  Век - определяемое существительное, эпоха - обособленное приложение, можно и так рассматривать,  принцип один и тот же, разницы никакой.

Comment: Это Куприн, у него это эмоциональное уточнение или пояснение  на грани со вставной конструкцией (никак не приложение): «необычайный - смутный и зловещий - гул, похожий на рев отдаленного моря, доносился от этой страшной, густой сжатой на этом пространстве массы». То есть это авторское. В художественных текстах вполне приемлемо. Нас же спрашивают: правильно ли? Возможно? Да, по аналогии с приложениями в конце предложения или со вставной конструкцией, но это не по правилам, а как авторское, для усиления эмоций. Здесь публицистика, возможны и тире, но по правилам запятые.

Comment: Можно и правило найти: ПАС § 80. Уточняющие члены при подчеркивании смысла выделяются или отделяются тире: Они [статуи] были расставлены прямо на земле и на газонах — без пьедесталов — в каком-то продуманном беспорядке (Кат.) — уточняется обстоятельство.  http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123

Comment: Sibylla, это же про уточнение (заметьте, не приложение, как Вы настаиваете), а у нас пояснение (нет смысла от широкого к узкому). Но как авторское, возможно обособление тире при подчёркивании смысла и при пояснении, так что в ЭТОМ случае по правилам запятые, а тире - авторское обособление, не по правилам.

Comment: Хорошо, останемся каждый при своем мнении. По-вашему автор сейчас уберет тире и поставит запятые, потому что "поясняющее обстоятельство" запрещается обособлять тире (есть, наверное, такое правило,  если Вы настаиваете, хотя в такой редакции мне не встречалось). А по-моему это авторская реплика-оценка, которую очень даже уместно сделать вставочной конструкцией и обособить тире. Реплика выделена, подчеркнута, текст получается выразительнее.

Comment: А вообще говоря, нашим правилам не хватает точности в терминологии, поэтому в заключение я сделаю попытку   эту терминологию улучшить. Есть очень удобный термин -  одноименные члены (иначе грамматически однородные члены, отвечающие на один вопрос и относящиеся к одному слову). По смыслу же они могут быть однородными, неоднородными, пояснительными, уточняющими и, что интересно, присоединительными. Присоединительные члены  - это неоднородные, уточняющие и пояснительные члены (а также другие втор. члены)  в добавочном сообщении, при бессоюзной связи присоединительные члены обособляются тире.

Answer (score 2):

По правилам должны быть запятые, это пояснительный член предложения.

Однако в веке двадцать первом,( то есть) в цифровую эпоху, чем больше мы погружаемся в компьютерные технологии, медиапространство и виртуальную реальность, тем больше наш мир начинает походить на иллюзию.